# How can I instantiate a variable?

Tags: python, database, instance

I have the following:

- objects

  - __init__.py
  - define.py

**define.py**:

```
 class Place:
     def __init__(self,name,inhabitants):
         self.name=name
         self.inhabitants=inhabitants
         myFunction.toStoreThings.on.db(name,inhabitants,'places')
     def someUsefulFunction(self):
         pass
```

If I run `import objects`, `moon=objects.Place('Moon',[])`, close the interpreter and open it again. I obviously loose the `moon` instance, but I have `(u'Moon',u'[]')` stored in the database. I already made `__init__.py` retrieve that information from the database and `unstring` it, but I'd also like it to instantiate `'Moon'` as `Moon=Place('Moon',[])`  so I can use `Moon.someUsefulFunction()` or `objects.Moon.someUsefulFunction()` even after I close the interpreter. How can I achieve this?

---

I was able to do it like this:

**__init__.py**:

```
# myFunction() creates a dictionary `objdic` of the stuff in the database
# >>>objects.objdic
# {'places' : [['Moon',[]]]}
instancesdic={}
instancesdic['places']={}
instancesdic['places'][objdic['places'][0][0]]=Place(*objdic['places'][0])
```

Which gives

```
>>> objects.instancesdic
{'places': {'Moon': <objects.Place instance at 0x1b29248>}}
```

This way I can use

```
objects.instancesdic['places']['Moon'].someUsefulFunction()
```

Which is ok, but I really wanted `objects.Moon.someUsefulFunction()`. Any attempt to call that whole thing `Moon` results either in:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Or in just the key in the dictionary being changed to an instance, instead of the `Moon` instance being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `setattr` function to set module attributes on the `objects` module, or you could update `globals` within that module.  So within your `__init__.py` you could do:

```
objDict = {obj[0]: Place(*obj) for obj in objdict['places']}
globals().update(objDict)
```

This will then let you do `object.Moon`, etc.

There is some danger to be aware of, though.  If any of your objects have the same name as anything else already created in `objects`, they will overwrite those things.  So if `objects` has a function called `myFunc` and then you create an object called `myFunc`, it could overwrite the function with the object.  (Which will overwrite which depends on which order you do things in.)

For this reason, it's probably not a good idea to do this automatically in `__init__.py`.  It can make sense to do this for ease of use in the interactive interpreter, but modifying globals in this way will get ugly if you use it in scripts.  It might be a better idea to create a function called `initGlobals` or something, and then call that function to set up your interactive environment.  If you put the code I showed above into such a function, then call it, it will set up the environment.  This lets you separate the simple importing of the module from actually creating global objects from the db, because sometimes you might want to do one but not the other.

Comment: The code worked and now I understand it'd be better off not doing what I was trying to do. I'll stick with a dictionary, then. Thank you.